# woocommerce share single ipn to multiple subdomain.

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have a website with multiple standalone wp installation in subdomain. It is not multisite installation.  Each of the wp installation has it own woocommerce shop enabled.

eg:

```
example.com // main site
first.example.com // subdomain 
2nd.example.com //subdomain
```

The problem , how do I use single paypal ipn url for all the websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I came out with.

Thanks [@ahmed-ginani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44560177/1310740) pointed out the script. There are still other works need to do because you cannot apply the script directly.

Basically this is what I do, define an custom Paypal ipn endpoint. This endpoint will redirect to the subdomain woocommerce ipn endpoint properly.

Here is the script:

In every subdomain where you have woocommerce paypal gateway enabled.

```
//first addding the woocommerce paypal ipn in the checkout field, this will be used when paypal sending back to the custom ipn endpoint. 

add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'add_web_paypal_url');
function add_web_paypal_url($args){

    $url = site_url();
    $ipn = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'WC_Gateway_Paypal', $url);
    /*we need to merge it into custom field*/
    $oldcustom = json_decode($args['custom'], true);
    $newcustom = array_merge($oldcustom , array('ipnurl' => $ipn) );
    $args['custom'] = json_encode($newcustom);  

    return $args;
}
```

Then in the main domain site (or the site you want to define the custom ipn endpoint), we forwards the paypal return data to proper ipn endpoint.

So, let say the custom ipn endpoint is https://www.example.com?action=ipn_forwarder

```
add_action( 'init', 'paypal_ipn_fowarder' );
function paypal_ipn_fowarder(){
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='ipn_forwarder'&& isset($_POST['custom']) ) {
        if ( ( $custom = json_decode( $_POST['custom'] ) ) && is_object( $custom ) ) {

            $ipnurl  = $custom->ipnurl;
            if(isset($ipnurl)){
                $data = array();
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $data []= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
                $data = implode('&', $data);

                $ch = curl_init(); /* Initialize */

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ipnurl);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                curl_exec($ch); /* Execute HTTP request */

                curl_close($ch); /* Close */

                header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200 );
                exit();
            }else{
                    return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

However , An IPN URL is site-specific so you cannot use the same URL for multiple domains. This would create a serious issue resulting in

- Membership Pro not being notified by PayPal of transaction status
- Errors on PayPal's side that might lead to suspending your PayPal account.

But still you can use the paypal IPN via filters requests by IP, Check out the script here for that : http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/11/how-to-setup-multiple-ipn-receivers-in-paypal/

Answer (score 0):

You can only configure the PayPal account to send IPNs to a single URL, however, you could then forward that data out to additional URLs if you want to.

Since you're using WordPress the best way to get this done would be to install [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-ipn-wordpress/), which is free, and then purchase the [IPN Forwarder extension](https://www.angelleye.com/product/wordpress-paypal-ipn-forwarder/).  What you would do is configure PayPal to send IPNs to the URL provided by the free plugin, and then the Forwarder will give you the ability to as many additional URLs as you need to forward the IPN data to so that they all run.

Of course, you could simply build your own IPN script that forwards the data as well if you don't want to use those plugins.